# Mapping real world in unity for Virtual reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I need a scene in Unity that matches the real world.

This guy made all i want.

https://twitter.com/vr_oasis/status/1218493216401608704

Is there any easy solution to solve this?

Thank You for Your Kindness ^o^

Comment: Well I'ld guess that "This guy" picked any 3d modelling program of his choice (Blender, Maya, ...) and built the required models and textures one by one ... so depending on what you would define as "easy" solution .. I'ld say: No there probably isn't. Ofcourse there is stuff like spacial understanding and room mesh tracking but to actually reconstruct the individual models from there is actually quite complex and requires AI and object recognition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want an easy solution,**

Get on a phone and go on the app store or google play store and find a 3D scanning app. Warning: older phones may not have the features that make 3d scanning possible.

Take a 3d scan of the room and export it to your computer.
The 3d model might not look that good so I'd recommend getting a 3d modelling program like [Blender](https://www.blender.org/). It will probably not look like what that guy made though.

You can try to 3d model everything from scratch like how the video probably did it but it will be timeconsuming.

If you want to replicate that video not only the 3d models:

Tracking the positions from the real world to virtual reality seems complex and hard. If you want an easy way, I'd recommend to fake it by using Unity Timeline to move the camera or somehow standing in the same place that you're scene starts when using VR.

Good Luck!

Comment: I've been researching it for a while, but your opinion seems to be the best.